# How to disable character encoding in gson?

Tags: java, xml, json, jaxb, gson

Gson directly encodes the characters like double quote(") by default when it converts a java object in json string. I have a array of xml data in a json object, as given below.

```
<items>
  <item id="100" name="test">
  </item>
</items>
```

I am using JAXB to create this XML structure using java objects, when I convert the constructed object to JSON using GSON, the xml output I get is given below,

```
<items><item id=\"100\" name=\"test\"></item></items>
```

How can I stop GSON escape the double quote? Please help.

Comment: So, you want a JSON generator to generate invalid JSON? That won't happen. Why would you want that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot stop GSON escape double quotes, because the output would not be valid JSON anymore. Each `"` would stop or start the current JSON string and the parts between would corrupt the JSON string.

However, this should not be a problem since a JSON parser will convert the `\"` back to `"` when deserializing anyway, because this is the specification of JSON.

See this very nice [JSON specification](https://json.org/), especially this part:

[image]
<sub>(source: [json.org](http://json.org/string.gif))</sub>